# Why does getHeaderNames returns an Enumeration in HttpServletRequest but a Collection in HttpServletResponse?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

[`HttpServletRequest.getHeaderNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaderNames%28%29) returns `Enumeration<String>` and [`HttpServletResponse.getHeaderNames()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeaderNames%28%29) returns a `Collection<String>`.

Why this discrepancy?

Comment: excellent question, as it seems unlikely that the HttpServletRequest is aware of every possible header, spec-based *and* framework-specific.

Answer (score 8):

Enumeration was used in combination with Hashtable and Vector. HttpServletRequest had the getHeaderNames method since jdk 1.2 and has not since been altered.

However HttpServletResponse did not have the getHeaderNames method until jdk 6 and by that time Collection was obviously preferred over the legacy Enumeration.

Answer (score 3):

The request method had implemented in java version 1.2.
and while collected were comes from jdk 6.

so by the time improvement of java they have used two different things collection and enumeration.

if you see response header values there will be no change in them if we modified collection.

Answer (score 1):

It may simply be because the request method was implemented before Collections API was added to java (I think in java 1.2).  It was a major improvement to java, and a great amount of java API are built on it.  However, some previous parts of the java API were built before on `Enumerations`, `Vectors` (before Vector implemented `java.util.List`), etc. ...  For compatibility it has remained that way.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you just get the values. In the second you get a reference to the collection that you *could* modify.

In the documentation they specify:

> Any changes to the returned `Collection` must not affect this `HttpServletResponse`.

So it is meant to be modified but the modification should not affect the response.

Comment: I know it does not completely explain what should be done but it shows the difference in the design

Comment: So it isn't meant to be modified.

Comment: @EJP I also get it like that but the formulation is pretty strange. They could just say that it should not be modified. Instead they say it can but without effects. It could be an error in the formulation or the author had something in mind.